# Why does the javascript line have to be in a function to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

If I put this javascript on my aspx page, the panel shows as expected upon button click:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowPopUp() {
     $('#<%= upNewClient.ClientID %>').show();
 }
 </script>

 <asp:Button ID="btnNewClient" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: ShowPopUp(); return false;" />
```

But if I try to do this w/o the function, it doesn't work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewClient" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: $'(%<= upNewClient.ClientID %>'.show(); return false;"/>
```

The page flashes and there might be an error appearing in my javascript console, but it comes and goes too quickly for me to read it.

So, why doesn't the exact same line of code work outside of the function?

**EDIT:**
I've rewritten this code several times (I'm actually trying to do it in the code behind), and I mistyped it the time just before my initial posting.  The actual button tag is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewClient" runat="server" Text="Add New Client" OnClientClick="javascript: $('#<%= upNewClient.ClientID %>').show(); return false;" />
```

This flashes an error in my javascript console very quickly that I believe says:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= upNewClient.ClientID %>

Comment: 1) You don't have to put `javascrpt:` 2) I don't think it is well formed

Comment: Read the code you've posted.

Comment: removing "javascript:" had no effect (even with correct syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<%= ... %>` syntax isn't supported within the attributes of a server-side control, so the whole thing gets sent to the browser:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnNewClient" value="Add New Client"
    onclick="javascript: $('#&lt;%= upNewClient.ClientID %>').show(); return false;"
    id="btnNewClient" />
```

Because jQuery can't parse the expression, it throws an exception.

Instead, you can set the button's `OnClientClick` property from the code-behind:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewClient" runat="server" Text="Add New Client" />
```

```c#
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    this.btnNewClient.OnClientClick =
        "$('#" + this.upNewClient.ClientID + "').show(); return false;";
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

(Setting the property in `Render` (instead of, say, `OnInit`, `OnLoad`, or `OnPreRender`) prevents the value from unnecessarily bloating view state.)

Comment: Awesome.  The aspx code I posted was in an attempt to solve the code behind issue. While I still don't understand why the same line of code works in a function but not outside of the function on the aspx page, your answer solved my actual problem.

I guess I thought the script string was being rendered as is to the page and therefore I needed the <%=... %> just like I would in the aspx page.  Now I know.  Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what actually gets rendered. The `<%= ... %>` syntax works inside the `<script>` block because it's not within the attribute of a `runat="server"` control.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `#` id selector for your inline and incorrectly placed quotes.. missing closing paren

so

```
$'(%<= upNewClient.ClientID %>'.show();
```

should be

```
$('#<%= upNewClient.ClientID %>').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error.`$'(%<=` should be `$('#<%=` and you forgot the closing parenthesis for `$(...)`

Comment: edited the post with correct syntax and the error I think I'm getting in the javascript console...

Answer (score -2):

i think the problem is with syntax, try changing it like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewClient" runat="server" OnClientClick="$('#<%= upNewClient.ClientID %>').show(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax error problem.  Now it flashes an error in my javascript so fast that it's hard to see, but I believe it is: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= upNewClient.ClientID %>

Comment: ooo yea, i frgt that...sorry

Comment: Downvoted because you forgot the '#' and you have a syntax error: `%<=` should be `<%=`

Comment: @mikemxm ya actually i paid more attention to the `'`